# Почему в postgresql не работает policy?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, policy

Выдается ошибка при всех действиях отличных от SELECT. Почему так и как починить?

Суть в том, чтобы разграничить строки для SELECT, но и сделать возможность вставки и так далее... Не понимаю, как это сделать.

Ошибка: new row violates row-level security policy for table

SQL:

```sql
ALTER TABLE api.message_history ENABLE ROW LEVEL SECURITY;

CREATE POLICY msh_pol ON api.message_history
FOR SELECT
USING (chat_users_id IN (
    SELECT
        cu.id
    FROM api.user u
    JOIN api.chat_users cu ON cu.user_id = u.id
    WHERE u.login = current_user
));
```

БД:

[image: БД]

Comment: Почему не используете WITH CHECK?

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич пробовал с аналогичными условиями и не выходило...

Comment: Дело в том, что "правильный" WITH CHECK согласно официальной документации как раз призван работать с INSERT и UPDATE...